# Re-runnable script to convert nullable columns to not nullable in an existing table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have found the solution below but I need this to be done using PL/SQL stored procedure.

```
declare
  l_nullable varchar2(1);
begin
  select nullable into l_nullable
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'PV_REPORT_DETAILS'
  and   column_name = 'FEED_ID';

  if l_nullable = 'Y' then
    execute immediate 'alter table PV_REPORT_DETAILS modify (Feed_ID  not null)';
  end if;

  select nullable into l_nullable
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'PV_REPORT_DETAILS'
  and   column_name = 'CURRENT_RUN_ID';

  if l_nullable = 'Y' then
    execute immediate 'alter table PV_REPORT_DETAILS modify (Current_Run_ID not null)';
  end if;

  select nullable into l_nullable
  from user_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'PV_REPORT_DETAILS'
  and   column_name = 'PREVIOUS_RUN_ID';

  if l_nullable = 'Y' then
    execute immediate 'alter table PV_REPORT_DETAILS modify (Previous_Run_ID not null)';
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: :What is the problem?,the anonymous block you have found is correct ,only thing is to wrap this is procecure .And yes this is re-runnable ,because the next time nullable column from user_tab_columns view will fetch "N"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Oracle's CREATE PROCEDURE syntax.  It should be what you are looking for.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm#i2072424

```
CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE procedure_name
    [ (parameter [,parameter]) ]

IS
    [declaration_section]

BEGIN
    executable_section

[EXCEPTION
    exception_section]

END [procedure_name];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the author wants a procedure that will make all nullable columns not null columns in a given table. Try this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE my_test_table (
  id NUMBER NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR2(20),
  salary NUMBER
);

DESC my_test_table;
```

```
Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
ID     NOT NULL NUMBER       
NAME            VARCHAR2(20) 
SALARY          NUMBER
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE nullable_to_not_nullable(p_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
AS
  CURSOR c_list_nullable_columns IS
    SELECT column_name
      FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = UPPER(p_table_name)
      AND nullable = 'Y';
BEGIN
  FOR v_rec IN c_list_nullable_columns
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_table_name || ' MODIFY (' || v_rec.column_name || ' NOT NULL)';
  END LOOP;
END nullable_to_not_nullable;
/

BEGIN
  nullable_to_not_nullable('my_test_table');
END;
/

DESC my_test_table;
```

```
Name   Null     Type         
------ -------- ------------ 
ID     NOT NULL NUMBER       
NAME   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
SALARY NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Comment: If you are crazy enough to name a table or column with special characters requiring quotes, then this will not work.